# Root finder vs. feedback loop

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, control-systems

I have a simulation that applies a force to a particle in a simple constant gravitational acceleration environment, and uses `FindRoot` in conjunction with `ParametricNDSolve` to estimate when to stop the applied force so that the particle flies through the origin of a Cartesian coordinate system. The code is as follows:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
g = 9.81; (*gravitational acceleration, m/s^2*)
T = 5000; (*thrust, Newtons*)
m = 1000; (*particle mass, kg*)
tmax = 145; (*simulation running time, seconds*)
x0 = 5000; (*initial x-position, m/s*)
y0 = 10000; (*initial y-position, m/s*)
vx0 = -200; (*initial x-velocity, m/s*)
vy0 = 10; (*initial y-velocity, m/s*)

F = If[t < thrusttime, T, 
  0]; (*applied force is stopped when t > thrusttime parameter*)

Solution = ParametricNDSolve[{
   x'[t] == vx[t],
   y'[t] == vy[t],
   vx'[t] == F/m,
   vy'[t] == -g ,
   x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, vx[0] == vx0, vy[0] == vy0}, {x[t], y[t], 
   vx[t], vy[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, {thrusttime}]

rootxy = FindRoot[{x[t][thrusttime] == 0, y[t][thrusttime] == 0} /. 
   Solution, {{t, 100}, {thrusttime, 26}}]
tflight = 
 rootxy[[1]][[2]] (*time when particle passes through (x,y)=(0,0)*)
tthrust = 
 rootxy[[2]][[2]] (*amount of time force must be applied to particle \
in order to get it to fly through the origin (x,y)=(0,0)*)

(*Plotting*)
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[{x[t][tthrust], y[t][tthrust]} /. Solution], {t, 0, 
  tflight}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10000, 10000}, {-10000, 10000}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

However, this seems to be a relatively unreliable method for manipulating the particle's trajectory, especially when using higher values of thrust and initial velocity. As such, I was wondering if, instead if using a root-finder, there is a way to instead incorporate a feedback system, whereby the particle's state `(x, y, vx, vy)` is constantly polled and the trajectory is integrated forward in time, during each polling event, to see if it will pass through the coordinate system's origin if the applied force is stopped when the polling event is performed.

It would be great if Mathematica was able to do something like this.

Comment: If the thrust is applied at t=0, the thrust has to be applied for the thrust time (tthrust ). Poling does not make sense, because once you know the thrust time, you can directly check whether t is greater than tthrust or not for a particular poling event, right?

Comment: Yup, however I'm trying to re-formulate the problem and solution without using a root-finder as it is an unreliable way to find the solution.

Comment: You can also solve the problem directly: `NSolve[{-(vx0 + T/m thrustT) (t - thrustT) == 
   x0 + vx0 thrustT + 1/2 T/m thrustT^2,
  -y0 == vy0 t - 1/2 g t^2}, {t, thrustT}]`